# Android: Usar id de componente como chave em Array

Tags: android, lista, bitmap

Tenho um app Android que possui **7 imageButtons**, preciso armazenar as imagens capturadas em um **List Bitmap**, estou tentando definir os indices do array list como o id dos **imageButtons**, entretanto o aplicativo da crash quando o procedimento é realizado.

```
public void tirarFoto(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
  System.out.println(view.getId());
  idBotao = (ImageButton) findViewById(view.getId());
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
  if(data != null){
    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
      Bitmap img = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
      idBotao.setImageBitmap(img);

      //TENTA ADICIONAR A IMAGEM NO ARRAY USANDO O ID DO BOTÃO COMO CHAVE
      testeArray.add(idBotao.getId(),((BitmapDrawable) idBotao.getDrawable()).getBitmap());


      Log.e("ID Button",String.valueOf((int) idBotao.getId()));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez seja algum problema relacionado ao index da lista, que no caso é o id do elemento *ImageButton*. Tente utilizar um *Map< int, Bitmap >* para adicionar seus elementos. Para cada *Entry* do *Map* você irá adicionar o id do elemento e o *Bitmap* da imagem capturada.